# Problem with Two Geometric Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Please consider the following problem and my attempt to solve it.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables having geometric
densities with parameters $p_1$ and $p_2$ respectively. Find $P(X >= Y)$.
Answer:
\begin{eqnarray*}
P( X >= Y ) &=&
 P( X = 0)P(Y <= 0) + P(x = 1)P(Y <= 1) \\
 &+& P(x = 2)P(Y <= 2) + P(X = 3)P(Y <= 3) + P(X = 4)P(Y <= 4) + ...  \\
P( X = 0) &=& p_1 \\
P( X = 1) &=& p_1(1-p_1) \\
P( X = 2) &=& p_1(1-p_1)^2 \\
P( X = 3 ) &=& p_1(1-p_1)^3 \\
P( X = 4 ) &=& p_1(1-p_1)^4 \\
P(Y <= 0) &=& p_2 \\
P(Y <= 1) &=& P(Y = 0 ) + P( Y = 1) = p_2 + p_2(1- p_2) \\
P(Y <= 2) &=& P(Y = 0 ) + P(Y = 1 )+ P( Y = 2) \\
P(Y <= 2) &=& p_2 + p_2(1- p_2)  + p_2(1- p_2)^2  \\
P(Y <= 3) &=& P( Y <= 2) + P(Y = 3) \\
P(Y <= 3) &=& p_2 + p_2(1- p_2)  + p_2(1- p_2)^2 + p_2(1- p_2)^3 \\
P(Y <= 4) &=& P( Y <= 3) + P(Y = 4)\\
P(Y <= 4) &=& p_2 + p_2(1- p_2)  + p_2(1- p_2)^2 + p_2(1- p_2)^3 + p_2(1- p_2)^4 \\
P( X >= Y ) &=&
 p_1( p_2 ) + p_1(1-p_1)( p_2 + p_2(1- p_2) ) \\
 &+& p_1(1-p_1)^2 ( p_2 + p_2(1- p_2)  + p_2(1- p_2)^2 ) \\
 &+& p_1(1-p_1)^3 ( p_2 + p_2(1- p_2)  + p_2(1- p_2)^2 + p_2(1- p_2)^3 ) \\
 &+& P(X = 4)P(Y <= 4) +  ...  \\
P( X >= Y ) &=&
 p_1( p_2 ) + p_1(1-p_1)( p_2 + p_2(1- p_2) ) \\
 &+& p_1(1-p_1)^2 ( p_2 + p_2(1- p_2)  + p_2(1- p_2)^2 ) \\
 &+& p_1(1-p_1)^3 ( p_2 + p_2(1- p_2)  + p_2(1- p_2)^2 + p_2(1- p_2)^3 ) \\
 &+& p_1(1-p_1)^4 ( p_2 + p_2(1- p_2)  + p_2(1- p_2)^2 + p_2(1- p_2)^3 \\
 && +p_2(1- p_2)^4  ) +  ...  \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Am I on the right track? Do I have a geometric series here? How do I complete the problem?

Bob

Comment: I haven't checked to make sure my approach works, but I think you are on the right track.  You might find helpful: the formula for the sum of a finite geometric series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the law of total probability, i.e., 
$$
\mathbb{P}(A) = \sum_i\mathbb{P}(A|B_i)\mathbb{P}(B_i),
$$
where $\cup_{i=1}^nB_i=\Omega$ and $B_i\cap B_j = \emptyset$ for $i\neq j$. Hence, 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X\ge Y) &= \sum_y\mathbb{P}(X\ge Y|Y=y)\mathbb{P}(Y=y)\\
                  & = \sum_{y=1}(1-p_1)^{y-1}(1-p_2)^{y-1}p_2\\
                  & = \frac{p_2}{ 1 - (1-p_1)(1-p_2)} \\
                  & = \frac{p_2}{p_1 + p_2 - p_1p_2},
\end{align}
where $\mathbb{P}(Y=y) = (1-p_2)^{y-1}p_2 $ and $$
\mathbb{P}(X\ge y | Y = y) = \sum_{y}(1-p_1)^{y-1}p_1 = (1-p_1)^{y-1}.  
$$

Comment: I am having trouble finding the last part. Can you put some more detail in right before the line $(1-p_1)^{y-1}(1-p_2)^{y-1}p_2$? By any chance did you forget a $\sum$? Also, the book's answer is $\frac{p_2}{p_1+p_2 - p_1p_2}$. Thanks. Bob.

Comment: Sure, I've edited the answer